# Object not found in laravel at localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm new in laravel. I have build a small project but i have faced a problem. Home page working fine but when clicking any inner page browser get Object not found. all route are ok. please help
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sovled by adding .htaccess